# In Synergy, Windows grabs my mouse when I hit Command-L in Mac

Tags: synergy

I'm using Synergy.  Windows is my server, my Macbook is my client.

Whenever I hit command-L on Mac, Windows locks its screen and steals the mouse focus.

It's rather annoying, as command-L is the Chrome/Opera hotkey to enter a new URL.

How can I fix this?  It would also be acceptable to block Windows from seeing the keystroke, as I never use it.

**EDIT:** I would like to still be able to lock the computer via other means.  Full disabling of Lock functionality is unacceptable.  I just want the hotkey disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975295/650475

Unfortunately, that appears to be the best that can be done.

Answer (score 4):

To disable the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Windows 7, XP or Vista) you may perform the following registry hack found at [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/)

> Open up regedit.exe through the start menu search box, and then browse
>   down to the following key, creating it if it doesn’t exist:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
> ```
>
> On the right-hand side, create a new DWORD 32-bit value named
>   DisableLockWorkstation and give it one of these values:
>
> 1 – Disable Lock Workstation
>
> 0 – Enable Lock Workstation
>
> The changes should be immediate, no need to restart anything.

There is also a downloadable .reg file that can also apply the update.

I have applied the hack and can confirm it does work on my Windows 7 machine

Comment: Will this disable the Lock function or the shortcut?

Comment: This will disable the shortcut only, you'll still be able to lock the computer from your start menu.

Comment: My dog.  You are super number one.

Comment: There's an issue for this in github:

https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/434

Comment: New address for that issue: https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/434

Comment: Uh oh-- I'm finding that this doesn't just disable Windows+L hotkey, _**it disables locking completely**_.  If I try to activate "Lock" via the start menu, nothing happens, and even after leaving my machine overnight I came back to find it did not require user/pass when I returned. This is not an acceptable solution for this problem.